# jQuery - Function - setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot understand what is incorrect in my jQuery code:

```
function BTTS(){

    $('#banner-title span').fadeOut('fast',function() {
        $('#banner-title span').replaceWith('Rental Program');
    };
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // RUN BTTS FUNCTION
    setInterval('BTTS()', 7500);
}
```

Comment: try `setInterval('BTTS', 7500)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow user2423612! When you say that this feature "doesn't work", what exactly do you mean? There are a lot of different meanings for this.

Comment: check your browser console to see whether there is any error

Comment: There's an error I checked. The problem that I'm almost positive is in the symbols. It's not in the right places I think. Symbols like { ) ;

Comment: You can use `$(this).replaceWith('rental program')` inside the complete function.

Comment: @karthikr No. @user2423612 You're using `}` where you should be using `})`. I recommend you to learn JS :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the code

```
function BTTS(){

    $('#banner-title span').fadeOut('fast',function() {
        $('#banner-title span').replaceWith('Rental Program');
    }); //<-- missing ')' here
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // RUN BTTS FUNCTION
    setInterval('BTTS()', 7500);
}); //<-- missing ')' here
```

Updated solution

```
var titles = ['My Title 1', 'My Title 2'], titleFlag = 0;
function BTTS(){
    $('#banner-title span').fadeOut('fast',function() {
        titleFlag = (titleFlag + 1) % titles.length;
        $('#banner-title span').html(titles[titleFlag]).show();
    }); //<-- missing ')' here
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // RUN BTTS FUNCTION
    setInterval(BTTS, 2000);
}); //<-- missing ')' here
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Z74Kg/)

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setInterval`. Also, you're missing a closing parenthesis after the last `}`.

Comment: @undefined same at the end of `ready()` also

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you! Anyone also know how I can get the titles to change each 7.5 seconds? So original title to title1 to title 2, then loop back to original title and so on. Loop it non stop.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: You still forgot to change `'BTTS()'` to `BTTS`. It'll introduce scope issues if OP happens to move the `BTTS` function into the callback.

Comment: Also consider changing setTimeout on `.delay(7500).fadeOut(...`