# jQuery - SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: jquery

I need help fixing my jQuery script. I'm not sure about the rules of jQuery. After this script runs, I need it to loop.

```
    <script>

$(document).ready(function(){

        var $title = $('#banner-title span').replaceWith('Testimonials');
    var $title2 = $('#banner-title span').replaceWith('Rental Program');
    var $title3 = $('#banner-title span').replaceWith('Services');

        $title.fadeIn('fast',function() {
        $title.delay(7500).fadeOut('fast',function() {
        $title2.fadeIn('fast',function() {
        $title2.delay(7500).fadeOut('fast',function() {
        $title3..fadeIn('fast',function() {
        $title3.delay(7500).fadeOut('fast');

        }); 
    }

</script>
```

Comment: This question does not provide enough information to answer. What's wrong?

Comment: I recommend reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Getting_Started and then http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/

Comment: `$title3..fadeIn` - that won't work with the double dots.

Comment: I would recommend going back further and learning the basics of programming. Looping is a very basic task that all programmers should be aware of.

Comment: Use a proper IDE for writing code since it can point out silly errors like this and learn how use browser debugging tools to debug javascript in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my updated answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765995/jquery-function-setinterval/16766015?noredirect=1#comment24155197_16766015)

```
var titles = ['My Title 1', 'My Title 2'], titleFlag = 0;
function BTTS(){
    $('#banner-title span').fadeOut('fast',function() {
        titleFlag = (titleFlag + 1) % titles.length;
        $('#banner-title span').html(titles[titleFlag]).show();
    }); //<-- missing ')' here
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // RUN BTTS FUNCTION
    setInterval(BTTS, 2000);
}); //<-- missing ')' here
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Z74Kg/)